# In reactjs, what is wrappedComponent.propTypes?

Tags: reactjs

Below code example is a simplified version a component. I don't understand the code at the bottom of this component, the Case.wrappedComponent.propTypes part. I can't find relevant document about wrappedComponent on Internet as well.

**Questions**:

1. What is wrappedComponent and propTypes key in it?
2. What do they do?
3. Where can I find document for these things?

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

   @inject('store') @observer
   export default class Case extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.caseId = this.props.match.params.id;


     this.setOtherComment = this.setOtherComment.bind(this)
     this.submitOtherComment = this.submitOtherComment.bind(this)
     }



     render() {
       return '...'
     }
   }

   Case.wrappedComponent.propTypes = {
     store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
     match: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
   };
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This is an API of `mobx-react` (with inject) and according to the [DOCS](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#using-proptypes-and-defaultprops-and-other-static-properties-in-combination-with-inject)

> Using propTypes and defaultProps and other static properties in combination with inject
>   Inject wraps a new component around the component you pass into it. This means that assigning a static property to the resulting component, will be applied to the HoC, and not to the original component
>
> ........
>
> if you want to make assertions on the data that is being injected
>   (either stores or data resulting from a mapper function), the
>   propTypes should be defined on the wrapped component. Which is
>   available through the static property wrappedComponent on the inject
>   component